# Ignore a column while doing MINUS in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written the query:

```
Select distinct a,b from t1 minus Select distinct a,b from t2.
```

Here t1 and t2 are two tables. I want distinct values of a and b that occur in t1 but not in t2. So I'm using minus operator. I want values of both a and b but I know that in some cases the value of b in t1 and t2 maybe different. This would result in values of a and b that are present in both t1 and t2 as minus would not happen if values of b do not match in both the tables. How can I do this successfully?

How can I get values of a and b that are present in table t1 but not in table t2 even though in some cases values of b might not match in both the tables?

```
    table1:                              table2:
column1  column2                    column1   column2
  1      a                             1         c
  2      b                             3         d
```

In this case I would want values (2,b) only. I would not want (1,a) as 1 is also present in table2.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I removed the inconsistent database tags.

Comment: Please tag your question properly!!!  Which dbms is this???

Comment: By the way the set operators `union`, `intersect` and `minus` already implicitly apply `distinct`.

Answer (score 2):

Start with `not exists`:

```
select distinct. . .
from t1
where not exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.a = t1.a and t2.b = t1.b);
```

From you describe, you might want the comparison only on `a`:

```
select distinct a, b
from t1
where not exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.a = t1.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the data not include in t2, you can either go for the NOT EXISTS or LEFT OUTER JOIN.
Here is the solution.

Using NOT EXISTS

`SELECT DISTINCT A,B FROM T1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T2 WHERE T2.A = T1.A AND T2.B = T1.B);`

Using Left Join

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2  ON T1.a = T2.a and T1.b = T2.b WHERE T2.a IS NULL AND T2.b IS NULL
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use sub query in the WHERE condition as below-

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM table1 A
WHERE A.column1 NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM table2)
```

You can also use LEFT JOIN as below which will provide you the same output as below-

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM table1 A
LEFT JOIN table2 B ON A.column1 = B.column1
WHERE B.column1 IS NULL
```